# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16) when building react with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

New to webpack with react. Getting this error when building webpack.

ERROR in ./dist/index.js 6:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
|

> ReactDOM.render(`<Fetch />`, document.getElementById("root"))

**dist/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Fetch from "../src/index"


ReactDOM.render(<Fetch />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './dist/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [  '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { 
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
            plugins:['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    progress: true
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react',
    'reactDOM': 'react-dom'
  },
};
```

**src/index.js**

```
import Fetch from './Fetch';

export default Fetch;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get Webpack to build using your `webpack.config.js` by removing the line:

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
```

which is located within the `rules` for `babel-loader`. I also changed the output's path to:

```
path: __dirname
```

Comment: let me give this a goooo.

Comment: do you know how to fix the `index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at index.js:1`

Comment: Yep, I got that too. I pushed my code up to a [repository](https://github.com/ydhan18/stack-overflow-webpack-fix-2). You can take a look at the `webpack.config.js`. You should be able to build and view your React app after removing the sections out of your `webpack.config`.

Comment: thanks this solved my issues tonight. Appreciate this a ton.

Comment: Nice, no problem.